# Installing adblock for FF4 from file?

Tags: firefox, adblock

Just installed FF4, and I'm trying to install adblock, but due to network policies, I cannot install it from the web site.

I've tried saving the xbi file (adblock_plus-1.3.3-fn+fx+sm+tb.xpi), and picking "Add addon from file", but I still get a message that says it's not compatible with FF4.

Is there a different file, or am I doing something wrong?  Is there any way to install extenstions without network connectivity?

Comment: Strange. Tried it on a virtual machine with a fresh FF4 installation. I downloaded the xpi file and then killed the connection on the virtual machine - FF would not let me install it. BUT - restored the connection and then it installed without any problems. Looks like FF is checking something over the connection and won't let you install without it..

Comment: @Siim: Right.  The problem is I'm behind a very aggressive firewall, so it can't connect to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround to avoid the compatibility test:

- Open `about:config` from the address bar
- Right-click somewhere on the preferences list and then select `New -> Boolean`
- Enter `extensions.checkCompatibility.4.0` as the preference name
- Set the boolean value to `false`

You should be able to install the add-ons now from file

A drawback is a nag message in the Add-ons Manager

Comment: Thank you!  One other drawback is that it will re-enable all of the disabled add-ons, some of which may actually be incompatible - you'll probably want to go and disable them and test before re-enabling them.